# How to force a part of program to run just once?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a c++ program that needs database and I'm using SQLite. I have a function, `createTables()`, that creates tables inside my database. But the part of program that really bothers me is that I have to call `createTables()` every time my program starts. Although SQL queries for creating tables are something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name
```

But I want to know if it's possible to run a part of code just once **without using `if` or other conditional statements.** Can I change the program workflow by itself? Can a program change itself?
For example suppose that the original code is :

```
createTables();
otherPartOfProgram();
```

But for next time ( suppose tables were created successfully in previous run ) Program changed itself and workflow is something like :

```
otherPartOfProgram();
```

Comment: What is your aversion to using control flow to do this? In any case, yes, it's possible, but ohmygod it's going to be such a pain to do properly that it's not worth it in the slightest.

Comment: Very weird question. Doesn't even mention *why* there's a need to avoid a conditional expression.

Comment: @slugonamission ~> I'm just curious about how to change a program by itself. The question is an excuse :)

Comment: You open the file within your program and re-write part of it. To do this, you need to know the format of the binaries on disk, the arch you're on, and where you call the `createTables()` function. Then you "simply" overwrite the jump with no-ops. Such a thing is basically impossible to get right first time and is completely out of the scope of a SO question.

Comment: Put the `createTables()` function in *another* program, and run that only once. Problem solved!

Comment: Given that you're using SQLite, can't you just distribute the database along with your program with the schema already existing?

Comment: @slugonamission Perrrrrfect Idea ! Thanks :)

Comment: I actually can't believe you didn't think of that :P

Comment: @slugonamission ~> :| thinking about how to change the program was the reason :) . I used ur idea in last project B-| :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That cannot be done directly. You could store *outside* of your program (configuration file, registry...) the fact that the tables were created, or change the `createTables` function so that you test whether they exist before trying to create them.

A simpler approach, though, is have the tables as a precondition to running your program. Have some external code create them.

Comment: I disagree. You can do it, just open the file, somehow find the offset to the function call and overwrite all setup/jump/teardown with NOPs and hope that any checksums still check out and all your addresses still match :P

Comment: @slugonamission: It could be slighly simpler... just overwrite the whole executable (i.e. provide a wrapper that creates the tables and runs the program, after successful creation of the tables in the first run, overwrite itself with a different executable that just calls the other --think 'executable' == 'script')

Comment: @slugonamission: That is what I thought I was hinting on the last paragraph... move the complexity outside of your program.

Comment: Aha, sorry, I was reading that as a completely separate program rather than a bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library has a solution, although it wasn't designed your for your situation:

```
#include <mutex>

std::once_flag flag;
void f();             // to be called once

void main_function()
{
    std::call_once(flag, f);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether to delete my answer, or leave it up to shame people into avoiding my bool approach :) [nevermind, it appears this is relatively new]

Comment: This does not tackle the issue. This ensures that the code is executed only once in this program run, what I understood from the question is that he wants the function to be run only on the first run of the program. (I.e. next run of the program should not try to create the tables)